# tinyMCE file upload unexpected token

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE plugin and want the ability to upload an image in the editor. I have everything to the point where I browse for an image and select it, but it before it tries to upload, I get 
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }*

I've setup my HTML like this:

```
<div id="htmlEdit"></div>

<form id="editorUpload" 
      target="hiddenFrame" 
      method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      style="width:0px;height:0;overflow:hidden">
      <input type="hidden" id="dzToken" name="dzToken">
      <input type="hidden" id="iField" name="iField">      
      <input name="image" type="file" onchange="$('#editorUpload').submit();this.value='';">
</form>

<iframe id="hiddenFrame"></iframe>
```

and initialized the editor like this

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:"div#htmlEdit",  
    theme: "modern",
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add: "styleprops",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste image textcolor colorpicker"
    ], 
        file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {                            
        if( type==='image' ){
            var tkn=getToken();                     
            $("#editorUpload").attr("action", "cgi/cmsUpload.exe");
            $("#dzToken").val(tkn);                                         
            $('#editorUpload input').click();                                                                                   
        }else{
            alertify.alert("images only please");
        }
        },                 
    height: 300,
    width: 928,
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    forced_root_block: "",
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons"
});
```

My biggest issue is that the *unexpected token }* error says it's on line 2 of the main HTML page, so I can't figure out where it is breaking, in my code or the TinyMCE.js file.

If I try the Firefox console, the error is:
*SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script*

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this line (found thanks to FireBug)

```
<input name="image" type="file" onchange="$('#editorUpload').submit();this.value='';">
```

I had to change it to

```
<input name="image" type="file" onchange='$("#editorUpload").submit();this.value="";'>
```

I just switched the single and double quotes.
For some reason the value='' was making the script fail.